# Why can't I redirect to the page using header()?

Tags: php, html

The problem is that the URL should redirect to Activated.php but it shows http://localhost/SP/activation.php/Activated.php rather than http://localhost/SP/Activated.php.

```
<?php
require 'db.php';
$msg='';

if(!empty($_GET['code']) && isset($_GET['code']))
{
  $code=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_GET['code']);
  $c=mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT pawnshop_id FROM pawnshop WHERE activation='".$code."'");

  if(mysqli_num_rows($c) > 0)
  {
    $count = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT pawnshop_id FROM pawnshop  WHERE activation='".$code."' AND business_status='0'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($count) == 1)
    {
        mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE pawnshop SET business_status='1' WHERE activation='".$code."'");

        //This the code where it should redirect
        header("Location: Activated.php");
    }
    else
    {
        $msg="Your account is already active, no need to activate again";
    }
  }
  else
  {
    $msg="Wrong activation code";
  }  
  mysqli_close($connection);
}

?>
<?php echo $msg; ?>
```

Comment: try to add `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('dispaly_errors',1);` at top of your page just after `<?php` and check exactly what error occurs?

Comment: Add slash / header("Location: /Activated.php");

Comment: From the manual, `HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as argument to » Location: including the scheme, hostname and absolute path, but some clients accept relative URIs. You can usually use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and dirname() to make an absolute URI from a relative one yourself`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: also after header add `exit();` so then the rest of the code doesn't run

Comment: @bader, right thinking -- but wrong implementation. The OP wants /SP/Activated.php: you have to add /SP/ also.

Comment: @bader URL shows http://localhost/Activated.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
header("Location: /SP/Activated.php");
```